# IDEA не распознает классы и пакеты в модуле

Tags: java, intellij-idea

После попытки создать (а потом и удалить) папку в директории *src* IDEA перестала распознавать классы и пакеты, как директории, однако раньше - все было в порядке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

---

**UPD_0:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Нужно каталог src пометить как источник исходного кода
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-content-roots.html
Правой кнопкой мыши на каталог src - mark directory as "sources"

Каталог должен подсветиться голубоватым цветом, по аналогии с каталогом "java" в вашем модуле чуть ниже

Answer (score 1):

У Вас указан модуль в основном "помнике"? Если да, то попробуйте "заимпортить" изменения "мавена" в идеи. Нажмите в самом нижнем левом углу идеи на иконку "киноленты", сбоку появятся разные вкладки, в том числе и "maven". Там будет кнопка "Import chages" или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: А где конкретно? Добавил фото с панелью Maven'a.